# JMeter JDBC Request Timeshift function - Time add variable multiplier

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, request, timestamp

I have a JDBC Request with a SELECT Statement that returns a bunch of data with timestamps. I needed to select data from a specific interval and increment the time so i wrote this timeshift function (postgresql db btw)

```sql
SELECT columns  FROM table
WHERE timest BETWEEN '${dataInc}'::timestamp AND '${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+01,${dataInc},P0DT0H0M10S,,dataInc)}'::timestamp;
```

dataInc stores the date value.

I created another variable called ${mult} where i define the value i want to multiply the seconds with.

[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQOiV.png)

So basically what i need its to do this (i know this is wrong sintax, im just writing this to explain my idea):

```sql
[...] P0DT0H0M(10*${mult})S, [...]
```

How can i do it since it is a string? Sorry for the confused question

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to increase number of seconds is `PT30S` you can replace your pattern with this. I have increased 30 seconds

This the complete function - `${__timeShift(hh:mm:ss,,PT30S,,)}`

I tried to simulate this in below screenshot
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the correct sintaxe, althought what i needed was a way to multiply the seconds with a variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) in order to perform the multiplication, something like:

```
${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+01,${dataInc},P0DT0H0M${__jexl3(10*${mult},)}S,,dataInc)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)